# Understanding browser timelines

Tags: time, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion server (running on localhost) and am attempting to optimise my application. My question relates to the information in the browser timeline (FF and Chrome return the same values).

I have a test cfm page that just returns about 100 bytes of static data. With CF debugging on it reports that the execution time is 3ms. The browser timelines, however, say that the browser is waiting for about 1.2 seconds. I fired up Fiddler and it also reported a similar time for the server side processing.

These discrepancies also occur (only are worse) when I test using pages that do real work. eg the difference between onrequeststart and onrequestend is 400ms but the browser "waiting time" is 2.2secs.

So, is this just "overhead" I cant do anything about or is there anything I can do to reduce the "waiting time"?

Comment: are you calling on the CF Port directly (8500) or using a web server (IIS, Apache, etc) in the middle?

Comment: Thank you. I am calling the CF server eg http //127.0.0.1:8501/app/person/1234 or http//www.mydomain.com/app/person/1234 (is a shared hosting with my hosting company). Is that what you meant? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off debugging and use cflog instead. The debugging is adding the extra overhead.

Comment: Thanks. I should have been clearer. I only turned debugging on to check the execution time. Then I turned all debugging off again. I just tested again and the browser "Waiting" on the timeline for the test page with no debugging or server monitoring etc is 1.14 secs for a page that takes 2ms to execute. Thanks again for your response.